# Longest Common Subsequence-Segmentation fault

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault

I have to write a program to determine the longest common sub sequence.

Input:

The first argument will be a file that contains two strings per line, semicolon delimited. You can assume that there is only one unique subsequence per test case. e.g.

XMJYAUZ;MZJAWXU

Output:

The longest common subsequence. Ensure that there are no trailing empty spaces on each line you print. e.g.

MJAU

I am using Dev C++ .. And it is compiling Fine!...But this question is a [programming challenge](https://www.codeeval.com/public_sc/6/) and when i submit my answer it's showing me a segmentation fault!

I have written the following code and i am getting a Segmentation Fault where am i wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
char str1[100],str2[100];
int len1;
int len2;
void printLCS(char b[len1][len2],char str1[],int i,int j)
{
    if(i==0 || j==0)
    return;
    if(b[i][j]=='c')
    {
        printLCS(b,str1,i-1,j-1);
        printf("%c",str1[i-1]);
    }
    else if(b[i][j]=='l')
    printLCS(b,str1,i,j-1);
    else
    printLCS(b,str1,i-1,j);
}
void Seq(char str1[],char str2[])
{

    int i,j;
    len1=strlen(str1);
    len2=strlen(str2);
    int LCS[len1+1][len2+1];
    char b[len1][len2];
    for(i=0;i<=len1;i++)
    {
        LCS[i][0]=0;
    }
    for(j=0;j<=len2;j++)
    {
        LCS[0][j]=0;
    }
    for(i=1;i<=len1;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=len2;j++)
        {
            if(str1[i-1]==str2[j-1])
            {
                LCS[i][j]=1+LCS[i-1][j-1];
                b[i][j]='c';
            }
            else if(LCS[i-1][j]>=LCS[i][j-1])
            {
                LCS[i][j]=LCS[i-1][j];
                b[i][j]='u';
            }
            else
            {
                LCS[i][j]=LCS[i][j-1];
                b[i][j]='l';
            }
        }
    }
    printLCS(b,str1,len1,len2);
}
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    if(argc!=2)
    {
        printf("Invalid Number of Arguments:\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen(argv[1],"r");
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("File can't be opened:\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    char c;
    c=fgetc(fp);
    while(c!=EOF)
    {
        int k=0;
        if(c=='\n')
        c=fgetc(fp);
        while(c!=';')
        {
            str1[k]=c;
            k++;
            c=fgetc(fp);
        }
        str1[k]='\0';
        c=fgetc(fp);
        k=0;
        while(c!=EOF && c!='\n')
        {
            str2[k]=c;
            k++;
            c=fgetc(fp);
        }
        str2[k]='\0';
        Seq(str1,str2);
        printf("\n");
        if(c==EOF)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        c=fgetc(fp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile for me(C11) `int len1;
int len2;
void printLCS(char b[len1][len2]`

Comment: @armin:So how should i pass the matrix b?I have defined len1 & len2 Globally!

Comment: The correct way, if you want a longer answer you should ask a new question about it.

Comment: @user2227862 Perhaps you missed Armin's point. The code doesn't *compile*, therefore it cannot seg-fault, therefore the question makes  little sense. Perhaps fixing the code so it compiles and thus exhibits  the problem would be a good starting point. (And it compiles for me, but I'm not running C11, which I find hard to be the culprit for the broken build, but thats another issue)

Comment: @WhozCraig The code seems to be correct http://ideone.com/vpQWNF My compiler must have a bad day. :(

Comment: Shouldn't you specify the compiler you're using?

Comment: Please tell me how should i proceed i hav mentioned the compiler!

Comment: @user2227862 I succeed to compile it and it is working fine :) I am using *gcc (GCC) 4.2.4 (Ubuntu 4.2.4-1ubuntu4)*

Comment: @user2227862 As you mentioned that your are using `Dev C++`, I guess you are using either `MinGw` or `cygwin`. You can check it by running `gcc --version` on your windows prompt (`cmd`)

Comment: `char c;
    c=fgetc(fp);` should be: `int c;
    c=fgetc(fp);` (the rest of the file handling is also rather clumsy)

Comment: *bump* Have you tried `int c; c = fgetc(fp);` yet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know system of this site but;
    i compiled with no error,
    and result was true.

```
You didnt close file. Maybe memory leak etc. didnt allowed by site.
```

And, dont use global variables, unless you dont know another solution

this usage is very very bad! ISO C90 forbids this, anyway

```
int len1;
int len2;
void printLCS(char b[len1][len2]...
```

good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got access to a Mac or Linux system, there's a fantastic tool called [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) which can help you track down these kinds of errors: basically it runs your program in a virtual machine and monitors what it reads and writes to memory.

Whilst I can't compile your code, I'm pretty suspicious about this for loop:

```
   for(i=1;i<=len1;i++)
{
    for(j=1;j<=len2;j++)
    {
        if(str1[i-1]==str2[j-1])
        {
            LCS[i][j]=1+LCS[i-1][j-1];
            b[i][j]='c';
        }
        else if(LCS[i-1][j]>=LCS[i][j-1])
        {
            LCS[i][j]=LCS[i-1][j];
            b[i][j]='u';
        }
        else
        {
            LCS[i][j]=LCS[i][j-1];
            b[i][j]='l';
        }
    }
}
```

Arrays in C and C++ start at 0, so the maximum offset you're interested in is probably `strlen - 1`. Try changing your for loops to

```
for(i=1;i<len1;i++)
{
  for(j=1;j<len2;j++) 
  {
     ...
  }
}
```

Comment: The adressed arrays have size+1, to allow for the begin/end conditions.

Comment: `LCS` does seem to be size+1, but `b` seems to be just `size`. `valgrind` gives an invalid write warning at line 44 when run a modified version of the file.

Comment: Have to admit, I'm surprised that it even prints anything: it doesn't look like the first elements of either dimension of b get assigned to.

Comment: I didn't look too deeply into the code, I stepped out two monthe ago after seeing the `char c;` thing. IMHO, the combination of CAPS LCS[][]  and one letter b[][] identifyers tells the rest of the story. The OP doesn't seem to have that much interest in it, either. Plus: the attempt to compile C code (with VLAs) with a C++ compiler.